# DB::count() is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I try to get the total number of columns in laravel but it gives me a different result my query is as below.

```
$sub = DB::table('purchase_payments')
        ->where('bill',"")
        ->where('round',1)
        ->where('final',0)
        ->where('calculate_payment',0)
        ->where('bill_avg_date', '<' , $today)
        ->distinct('bill_link')
        ->count();
```

After that, I try it using `DB::raw` but it gives me a syntax error

```
$due = DB::table('purchase_payments')
        ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT bill_link  where `bill` = "" AND `round` = 1 AND `final` = 0 AND `calculate_payment` = 0 AND `bill_avg_date` < ' . $today));
```

error :
[image]

Please help me to achieve to correct count.

Comment: Why are you using double `where` for column `bill` ? Can you explain ?

Comment: sorry it was by mistake.

Comment: can you post detailed error..?

Comment: Are you looking for columns where bill is NULL or empty string? If it is null you need to use whereNull('bill')

Comment: @ZaheerAttar first one gives me wrong output and the second one gives me an error so I will put error log of the second one.

Comment: @rypskar `bill` is not null it's empty.

Comment: try `where('bill', '=', '')` instead of `where('bill',"")`

Comment: Do you have problem while executing raw query or first one query ?

Comment: yes @SagarGautam

Answer (score 0):

I think query forming here is wrong. Can you check what query is being generated here?

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$due = DB::table('purchase_payments')
    ->count(DB::raw('DISTINCT bill_link  where `bill` = "" AND `round` = 1 AND `final` = 0 AND `calculate_payment` = 0 AND `bill_avg_date` < ' . $today));
print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```

This will print your current query. There might be some syntax missings

Answer (score 0):

You should try this query

```
       $query=DB::table('purchase_payments as pp')
        ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT(pp.bill_link)) as bill_count'))
        ->where('pp.bill',"")
        ->where('pp.round',1)
        ->where('pp.final',0)
        ->where('pp.calculate_payment',0)
        ->where('pp.bill_avg_date', '<' , $today)
        ->get()
```

Comment: add `count()` instead of `get()`. Question is about counting

Answer (score 0):

For your `raw` query, the date must be quoted:

```
... AND `calculate_payment` = 0 AND `bill_avg_date` < "' . $today . '"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this.. you need to specify what you want to count if you use groupby or distinct

```
$sub = DB::table('purchase_payments')
        ->where('bill',"")
        ->where('round',1)
        ->where('final',0)
        ->where('calculate_payment',0)
        ->where('bill_avg_date', '<' , $today)
        ->distinct('bill_link')
        ->count('bill_link');   <---
```